# Reduce the execution time when handling the server response?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I have a server, and I need to get some data from it.  At the very beginning, I utilized the `curl` to get the raw `JSON` response, it's rapid but insufficient for me. I need to convert the raw `JSON` to some special format.

Therefore, I try to use the `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to write such kind of script.

Here is my code snippet:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

........
        url="xxxx" //It is not the localhost but the server on other region
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url.toString()).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String str = null;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //The format of response is JSON 
            while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //read and convert the raw data to some special data struct
                //The time overhead of this part is trivial
            }
..........
```

When I try to get a little data (i.e., only contains a few lines), the above snippet wouldn't be stuck at `while(xxxx)` significantly. However, with the increment of my data size (more than 3000 lines), too many  times `while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)`  make the total time unacceptable.

Can anyone give me some suggestions about:

- Based on `HttpURLConnection`, how to optimize my code in oder to reduce the extra time?
- Whether there exist some good Java 3rd-part alternatives to `HttpURLConnection` and suit for me to work under such high latency-critical scenario?
- It is possible to get the content at one time without the `while` loop?

**Additional**:

From localhost:

[image]

From remote server:
[image]

Comment: Do you have some numbers here? What is the latency target? Have you profiled your code to determine where the overhead is?

Comment: @PiRocks The ultimate target should [7000 lines: within 1s (maybe 600ms)], My code only performs [7000 lines: 5471 ms] , how can I make some progress?

Comment: How much is your data in megabytes? 5.4 seconds seems like a long time for 7000 lines, unless these lines are quite long. I would also advise checking that the buffered reader is in fact the bottleneck in a profiler.

Comment: @PiRocks I set variable `start` and `end`  that wrap the `while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)` and calculate the time. Maybe execute 2 or 4 times of `readLine()` will increase 1ms.

Comment: Have you tried without a buffered reader? A profiler would hopefully be able to tell you if the overhead is coming from IO or the overhead of the buffered reader.

Comment: @PiRocks Each line of data looks like `{"table":{"name":"xxxxxx","pointName":"xxxxx","status":"3"},"timestamps":[xxxxxxxxxxxxxx],"values":[xxxx]}`. Without a buffered reader is my current goal, and I am seeking the alternative way.